# Flutter Error "Failed to build iOS App (...)"

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

The error appeared random after I hot reloaded my project yesterday. It haven't changed since I restarted my MacBook, run Flutter doctor and run Flutter pub get.
Flutter doctor can't find any issues.
I use MacOS Monterey 12.0.1 (21A559) with Visual Studio Code
(Version: 1.67.2 (Universal)).
Dart:html is already imported.

````
Xcode build done.                                           11,1s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    2022-06-05 09:39:25.921 xcodebuild[1749:16344] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
    2022-06-05 09:39:25.922 xcodebuild[1749:16344] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
    ** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
    Writing result bundle at path:
        /var/folders/gj/s6gx23gj2b757fmstrdbl2pc0000gn/T/flutter_tools.dWhLgy/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirIiSM3d/temporary_xcresult_bundle
Invalid depfile: /Users/jakobschreiber/Developer/projects/Flutter/bmi_rechner/.dart_tool/flutter_build/0f8c8ef77632dcfa59aca1534c60a037/kernel_snapshot.d
Invalid depfile: /Users/jakobschreiber/Developer/projects/Flutter/bmi_rechner/.dart_tool/flutter_build/0f8c8ef77632dcfa59aca1534c60a037/kernel_snapshot.d
Invalid depfile: /Users/jakobschreiber/Developer/projects/Flutter/bmi_rechner/.dart_tool/flutter_build/0f8c8ef77632dcfa59aca1534c60a037/kernel_snapshot.d
Invalid depfile: /Users/jakobschreiber/Developer/projects/Flutter/bmi_rechner/.dart_tool/flutter_build/0f8c8ef77632dcfa59aca1534c60a037/kernel_snapshot.d
: Error: Not found: 'dart:html'
    import 'dart:html';
           ^
    Unhandled exception:
    FileSystemException(uri=org-dartlang-untranslatable-uri:dart%3Ahtml; message=StandardFileSystem only supports file:* and data:* URIs)
#0      StandardFileSystem.entityForUri (package:front_end/src/api_prototype/standard_file_system.dart:34:7)
#1      asFileUri (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:658:37)
#2      writeDepfile (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:798:21)
    <asynchronous suspension>
#3      FrontendCompiler.compile (file:///opt/s/w/ir/cache/builder/sdk/pkg/frontend_server/lib/frontend_server.dart:623:9)
    <asynchronous suspension>
#4      starter (file:///opt/s/w/ir/cache/builder/sdk/pkg/frontend_server/lib/frontend_server.dart:1447:12)
    <asynchronous suspension>
#5      main (file:///opt/s/w/ir/cache/builder/sdk/pkg/frontend_server/bin/frontend_server_starter.dart:10:14)
    <asynchronous suspension>
    Failed to package /Users/jakobschreiber/Developer/projects/Flutter/bmi_rechner.
    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning
    note: Build preparation complete
    note: Building targets in dependency order
    Result bundle written to path:
        /var/folders/gj/s6gx23gj2b757fmstrdbl2pc0000gn/T/flutter_tools.dWhLgy/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirIiSM3d/temporary_xcresult_bundle
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 13 Pro Max.
Exited```


    Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, 3.1.0-0.0.pre.828, on macOS 12.0.1 21A559 darwin-arm, locale de-DE)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.4.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.67.2)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability

• No issues found!
````

Answer (score 3):

My best guess is that while working on your project you accidentally imported `dart:html` or something that uses `dart:html`.

And as described on the API documentation for Dart: https://api.dart.dev

> dart:html: DOM manipulation for web apps (available only to web apps).

Which means you can not build something with `dart:html` for iOS.

Try looking into recently added imports!

Comment: Yup! Had the same problem and just removed the import (dart:html), which was not being used, and it works again. Thanks!